# Bootstrap alert firing ajax request on dismiss

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap2. The following is HTML markup in an ASP.NET MVC4 AJAX form -

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ItemPost", "Supervisor", null, ajaxOptions, new { @id = "frmItem" }))
{
<button id="btnShowNewItemDiv" class="btn pull-right">
    <i class="sm-icon-cube"></i>&nbsp;<span id="newItemSpan">@Supervisor.IBtnNewItem</span>
</button>

<div id="NewItemDiv" style="display: none;">
    <h2 class="h2NewItem">@Supervisor.Ih2</h2>

    <div id="itemContent">
        <div class="alert alert-info fade in">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" formnovalidate>x</button>
             Some text here
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have intentionally omitted rest of code to make code short.

### Problem

On click of dismiss button in bootstrap alert, it is performing ajax call and submitting form. ***How do I avoid this behavior?***

Comment: add the `type` attribute to your button ie `<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">`

Comment: I made a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/25Epk/

Comment: @CarrieKendall I tried your suggestion. And now the alert box doesn't closes.

Comment: I don't know what exact version you're using, but bootstrap 2.3.2 works this way, view the documentation if you need a solid example: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both comments from *@Verkion* and *@Matt* are sufficient to resolve this issue. *But not in context with Bootstrap.*

Because my earlier **MVC4 + Bootstrap** applications were/are working fine with same conditions. I investigate further what could be the real cause?

Finally I found a stupid solution. ***The solution was to include bootstrap-alert script file*** *("~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js")* in ajax page.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using an ajax.beginform put your ajax call into a button click event

```
$('#btnShowNewItemDiv').on('click', function(){
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                //do something with the result
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default behavior of the button is to trigger the `POST`. 
Try this, to stop the default behavior:

```
$(function() {
  // wire up close button click event
  $("#itemContent button").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
     var alert = $(this).closest('.alert'); 
     $(alert).alert('close'); // close the alert
  });
});
```

Comment: .. Or set the type in the markup... There's absolutely no need to use javascript